# Application.js script blocked in "queuing" state until images have loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, google-chrome-devtools, domcontentloaded

Our site has an asynchronously loaded application.js:

`<script async="async" src="//...application-123456.js"></script>`

Additionally, we have a lot of third party scripts that (1) are asynchronously loaded, and (2) create in turn an async `<script>` tag where a bigger script is called.

Just to give an example, one of these third party scripts is [Google's gpt.js](http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js) (you can have a quick look to understand how it works).

**Our problem is that, while all the third party scripts load asynchronously as expected, the application.js one gets stack in "queuing" status for more than 4 seconds.**

I tried to change the script and make it load like the third party ones: create a `<script>` element, set the "src" attribute and load it:

```
<script async>
    (function() {
        var elem = document.createElement('script');
        elem.src = 'http://...application-123456.js';
        elem.async = true;
        elem.type = 'text/javascript';
        var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, scpt);
    })();
</script>
```

but nothing changed.

Then I studied the network cascade in a page of our site that almost doesn't contain images, and I saw that the queuing time was almost zero. **I tried the same experiment in pages with different amounts of images, and saw that the queuing time proportionally increases in pages with more images.**

I read this in [Chrome's network cascade documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing):

> QUEUING TIME: The request was postponed by the rendering engine because it's considered lower priority than critical resources (such as scripts/styles). This often happens with images.

Is it possible that for some reason the browser is marking our `application.js` as "lower priority"? I looked on the web and it seems that nobody has experienced problems with the queuing time. Anybody has an idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers use a pre-loader to improve network utilisation. [This article](http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/) explains the concept.

In the [Chrome Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing) you linked to above, it says the following about queuing:

> If a request is queued it indicated that:
>
> - The request was postponed by: the rendering engine because it's considered lower priority than critical resources (such as scripts/styles). This often happens with images.
> - The request was put on hold to wait for an unavailable TCP
>   socket that's about to free up. The request was put on hold because the browser only allows six TCP connections per origin on HTTP 1.
> - Time spent making disk cache entries (typically very quick.)

The pre-loader would have retrieved the lightweight resources quickly, such as the styles and scripts, and then queued up the images because, as the criteria above suggests, only 6 TCP connections are permitted per origin. Therefore, this would explain the delay in the total response time.

Comment: Thank you @Gideon, that article was very interesting and explained how the pre-loading is supposed to work. However, my problem is still there: I have a <script> tag that comes after the <img> tags, so the pre-loader should give priority to the <script> but this is not happening. Do you have an idea about which could be the cause?

Comment: In the 'Pre-Loader Gotchas' section of the article, it mentions that the pre-loader can't execute JavaScript, so your script source doesn't get looked at until the JavaScript gets executed later to insert the DOM element. You could try `<script async src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: I found a way to make it work as expected: I moved the `<script src="application.js" async>` in the `<head>` tag (before it was on the bottom of the `<body>`). After this change, the script is correctly downloaded before the images. Still, it remains a mystery why before it wasn't working.